# Method that calculates percentage change between 2 numbers returns wrong number

Tags: java, debugging, math, double, percentage

So i have this method that calculates the percentage change of the 2 numbers.

```
public static double getChange(double start, double end) {
    return ((end - start) / start) * 100;
}
```

This outputs 1.0000000000000009

```
getChange(1, 1.01)
```

And this outputs -0.990099009900991

```
getChange(1.01, 1)
```

But they  both output wrong specially the below one. The first one should be 1 and the second -1. Is something wrong in my math or is this just some wierd thing in java? And how would i fix it so it would return the right percentage change.

Comment: Don't rely on double or float when you need precise floating point values, use BigDecimal instead.

Comment: Check your math, second should not be -1